# What is this straight line at the beginning of the measure?

Tags: theory, piano, notation

[image]

Could this just be a error on the editors part? Is it possible that i could also be a ghost note of some sort?

Comment: It looks like an error. I think it's simply a barline in the wrong place.

Answer (score 18):

This is definitely an error. I would stay away from whomever edited / published this music.  Nothing is vertically aligned and the print quality is abhorrent.

Comment: Had to look twice for lack of quality - found it! The L..H. notes  don't line up with the R.H. notes. That errant line could have been a correct stem... +1.

Comment: Cripes, that's an absolutely horrible job of typesetting!

Answer (score 10):

This very much looks like an error perpetrated in cohorts with the typesetting program in question.

Note that the second staff has its music shifted by a quarter note to the right starting with the strange vertical line.  This offset gets reduced without apparent reason to circa an eighth note in the middle of the third bar.

So it very much looks like editing gone wrong several times in a row.  Figure out what program was used for producing this score and stay away from it as it seems to make it too easy for things to go out of whack.  More importantly: stay away from scores this composer created using this program.  They are not a good team so far.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an error, yes, but it could also be a pickup measure. I'd lean more towards the error consensus though.

Comment: A pickup measure is on all staves. It cant be that even when I'm looking farfetched.

Comment: @Nachmen I realize that but I was just going on a whim. I swear I've seen them like that before though.

Comment: Is that correct notation?